# Bluebird Error: Generator Function Must Be A Function

Tags: javascript, promise, generator, bluebird

I am getting the error:

```
bluebird.js:2118 Uncaught TypeError: generatorFunction must be a function
```

But I don't understand why this error is occurring, as I am passing it a generatorFunction.

```
export class Welcome {
    fetch() {
      Promise.coroutine(this.userData());
    }

    userData = function* getData() {
     this.lotsData = yield this.testApi.getMock();
     this.lotsData = JSON.stringify(this.lotsData, null, 4);
    }
}
```

So a click event calls fetch() and that calls this.userData(). This is the console dump of this.userData:

```
GeneratorFunctionPrototype {}
_invoke: invoke(method, arg)
__proto__: GeneratorFunctionPrototype
```

Which tells me it most certainly is a generator. I am using all of this in an aurelia class if that somehow makes any difference (which it shouldn't I don't think). So why is it erroring that the generatorFuction must be a function?

Comment: What line number is the error thrown on?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. [See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What you actually want is `fetch = Promis.coroutine(userData)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limited amount of code you posted is riddled with errors, but there is not enough to know what is correct and what is incorrect.

One thing is for sure `this.userData()` is a function **call** and not a reference to a function, which is what `.coroutine()` is expecting.

Whatever type returned by `this.testApi.getMock()` is what is being `yield`ed, which we have no idea given what you posted, but that is probably not even relevant at this point, because what is returned is probably `unknown`/`null` anyway because you are assigning the `yield` to a variable of questionable scope. Your code is nowhere near the example from the documentation

```
PingPong.prototype.ping = Promise.coroutine(function* (val) {
    console.log("Ping?", val)
    yield Promise.delay(500)
    this.pong(val+1)
});
```

The [documentation](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.coroutine.html) has a very clear and well defined example you should follow, explicitly until you understand what you are actually doing.

Comment: I see your point. I will try playing around with it some more.

Comment: Actually `this.testApi.getMock()` works. Its just another class that has been imported and it returns a promise from a fetch. Other than `Promise.coroutine(this.userData());` I am not sure what other errors exist. If I write my own generator runner I am able to make it work fine. I was trying to use Bluebirds in lieu of my custom generator runner.